# What is the alternative for modern experience "most viewed item"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I know that classic experience has this option where you can see the most viewed items inside a document library.

What is the equivalent of this feature inside modern experience document library?

We have thousands of files, and only a few of them are frequently used. Views and filtering are used but don’t really solve this problem.

Is there a way so the default of Document Library shows only the most used items and not thousands of other items that are rarely used?

Keeping in mind that I can’t know which items are mostly used due to the fact that our Sharepoint online has a of of users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Highlighted Content Webpart to a modern page. with these settings:

**Content**

- Source: this site
- Type: Documents
- Document Type: any

**Filter and sort**

- Filter: leave blank
- Sort by: **Most viewed**

[image]

### If you need to target specific library only, you can use these settings:

- Custom query

**Query**

- Source: This site
- Query text (KQL): `ContentTypeId:0x0101* path:"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/*"`
- Sort by: **Most viewed**

[image]

Comment: I don't see anywhere this "•Custom query"

Comment: Chances are your tenant doesn't have this update rolled out yet. Maybe you can check it in a week or so.